# With a hidden element, you reference the ID to get the posted value, what is name for then?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

With a hidden element, you reference the ID to get the posted value, what is name for then?

Just wondering, do I even have to add that attribute in the HTML?

Comment: This question could be clearer. What's the "posted value"? And what are you trying to do?

Comment: if someone clicks button1, I want to pass a 'reject' value, and if somone presses button2, I want to pass a 'approve' value.

Answer (score 1):

With any form element, including hidden type ones, only the name of the element is used to name the posted value.

You have to add the name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
hidden_field_tag 'token', 'VUBJKB23UIVI1UU1VOBVI@'
```

in your view, you'll access the value in your controller with

```
params[:token]
```

Is that what you're asking?